# Code Chef Counting Pretty Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I am doing code chef problems. I am stuck on this one. The problem is simple one.
https://www.codechef.com/LTIME61B/problems/NUM239

Vasya likes the number 239. Therefore, he considers a number pretty if its last digit is 2, 3 or 9.
Vasya wants to watch the numbers between L
and R (both inclusive), so he asked you to determine how many pretty numbers are in this range. Can you help him?

I wrote a solution in O(T) which is giving correct answers for my inputs. But shows wrong answer on codechef.
Is there any corner case I am missing?
My code is:

```
    public class Solution {
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        int T = scanner.nextInt();
        for( int i = 0; i < T; i++ ) {
            int prettyNumbers;
            int L = scanner.nextInt();
            int R = scanner.nextInt();

            prettyNumbers = ( (R/10) - (L/10) ) * 3;

            if( R%10 > 1 ) {
                prettyNumbers++;
                if( R%10 >= 3 ) {
                    prettyNumbers++;
                }
                if( R%10 == 9 ) {
                    prettyNumbers++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println( prettyNumbers );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging is an integral part of programming. In this case you can easily find "corner cases" by writing a "naive" implementation and running it against your implementation of all pairs of `L` and `R` from 0 to 100.

Comment: What does your program output for the range `[4, 14]`?

Comment: Hint: such stuff is *perfect* for TDD. Meaning: instead of first writing all the code, to hope it works, you start by writing a simple test. Then you write code to solve the test. And so on ...

Comment: R = L = 3, your program gives wrong output

Answer (score 0):

```
class Codechef {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i =0;i<t ;i++ ){
            int l = sc.nextInt();
            int r = sc.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            for(int j=l;j<=r;j++){
                 if(j%10==2){
                count++;`
            }
            else if (j%10==3) {
                count++;
            }
            else if(j%10==9){
                count++;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

input is :

```
2
1 10
11 33
```

output is :

```
3
8
```